# Distinguish multiple iPhone hotspots

Tags: iphone, ios, tethering

I often work in trains or at other locations where many people are close together. I share the Internet connection of my iPhone with my other devices for this purpose. What do I do if several people around me have activated the [personal hotspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_%28Wi-Fi%29) of their iPhones? They all have the name "*iPhone*". How do I know which iPhone is the correct one?

It seems to me that several people have problems connecting multiple devices to one iPhone. But, I did not find this question so far.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the name of your iPhone.

Go to *Settings* → *General* → *About* → *Name*, and then rename your phone to something meaningful.

When you activate your hotspot, it will show this new name.

Comment: Isn't "give *your* phone a unique name" a generally good idea anyway?

Comment: @RonJohn it depends, maybe you want to avoid to be easily spotted in a train or similar („ah, ‚RonJohn‘s iPhone‘, let‘s have a chat with them“).

Comment: @nohillside unique doesn't have to mean personally identifiable.

Comment: I name my phone "Network_Virus"

Comment: @RonJohn Unique implies identifiable. Once somebody knows your phone is called "Painpoint", they also know it's you if you see the name in the WiFi list.

Comment: @nohillside but that's the trick, isn't it?  Why should some rando on the train know that *my* iPhone is name "Painpoint", or even that *my* name is Ron (when he sees that "Ron's iPhone" exists among all the other iPhones on train).

Comment: @RonJohn Not some random person, but the friend you had an argument with last week and don't want to see right now :-) But in general I agree that having a unique name for a device brings a lot of benefits as well.

Comment: @nohillside: If that's a concern (and I guess it may well be for some people, some of the time), you can always give your phone a new random name just before activating it as a hotspot each time.